# Device Manager is constantly refreshing - what is wrong?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I ran into an quite odd problem, after installing some drivers on my Lenovo N100 0768 (Windows 7) notebook and attaching an USB-HDD.

Now I have sound, but constantly the *device dicsonnected* sound - like every 2 seconds!

Looked at the device manager and it is flashing together with the sound.

A quick search on the net directed me towords driver issues or issues with attached usb-devices. No big suprise here - but how can I solve this?!

Answer (score 6):

Solved this by using [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) by NirSoft.

There might be other tools around, I do not intend to advertise it, but it actually did the job in this case.

The problem was the only driver Lenovo lists, when select Windows 7 as OS. I've installed it, it's the *Lenovo System Interface Driver* and has to do with the *softkeys*, like monitor-switch, wlan-features, etc. on F1-F12.

Somehow, when installed, it tries to install the *AuthenTec AES2501B* device, which seems to be the fingerprint-sensor. However, it starts to switch constantly between active and inactive state, and that is why the device manager starts flashing and creating disconnect sounds.

The solution was to use USBDeview to remove the *AES2501B* and other suspicious USB-devices, which were not listed in the device manager anymore. Then found out that the AES would come back on every use of a shortkey.

I am still working on the proper driver installation, because now, whenever I use a shortcut key, this behaviour starts again.

Comment: For me it was `Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB QDLoader 9204` (also a Lenovo Notebook). It also caused `explorer.exe` constantly burning CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I noted this issue when I was trying to fix Bluetooth on my Windows 10 system. Turned out it as the bluetooth driver. When I uninstalled it, the refreshing went away.

I reinstalled it but refreshing also returned. I made sure to enable "View Hidden devices" from view menu and it did show several previously connected bluetooth devices. I uninstalled them too.

I repeated doing this about a few times until the next time the refreshing stopped! And I noticed my bluetooth issue was also fixed (I was not seeing the bluetooth on/off setting in system settings previously). And my bluetooth is working too!